# How can you printf or echo the contents of your clipboard?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, clipboard, echo

Alternatively, how can you dump the contents of your clipboard to a text file? If at all possible, I'd like this for the actual clipboard, but also the clipboard delegated to highlighted text, and even vim's if you can manage it.

I figure if you can at least echo it, then you should be able to `>` into a file pretty easily.

Comment: Vim's registers are internal to it, unless you use the `*` or `+` registers, in which case it uses the clipboard(s)

Answer (score 4):

Job for `xclip`:

```
xclip -o >file.txt
```

- `-o` dumps the current clipboard (precisely selection) content to STDOUT, then you can simply leverage a shell redirection

---

`xclip` comes with `xclip` package, you might need to install it first.

Comment: two clipboards; that seems to work for highlighted text. Now what about copied text?

Comment: @Akiva X11 server has clipboard, which is where copied text goes, and two selections, primary and secondary.  `xclip -sel clip -o` releases copied text. Just read tye manual for `xclip` , there's plenty of options